# 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'output'

Tags: shell, output, wildcard, rules, snakemake

I get an error for a rather simple rule. I have to write a task file for another program, expecting a tsv file. I read a certain number of parameters from my config file and write them to a file with a shell command.

Code:

```
rule create_tasks:
    output:
        temp("tasks_{sample}.tsv")
    params:
        ID="{sample}",
        file=lambda wc: samples["path"][wc.sample] ,
        bigwig=lambda wc: samples["bigwig"][wc.sample] ,
        ambig=lambda wc: samples["ambig"][wc.sample] 
    shell:
        
        'echo -e "{params.ID}\t{params.file}" > {output}'
```

When I execute the workflow, I get the following error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Using shell: /usr/bin/bash
Provided cluster nodes: 1
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        1       create_tasks
        1

[Mon Oct 12 14:48:15 2020]
rule create_tasks:
    output: tasks_sampleA.tsv
    jobid: 0
    wildcards: sample=sampleA

echo -e "sampleA    /Path/To/sampleA.bed               " > tasks_sampleA.tsv
WorkflowError in line 23 of /path/to/workflow.snakefile:
'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'output'
  File "/path/to/miniconda/envs/snakemake_submit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 111, in run_jobs
  File "/path/to/miniconda/envs/snakemake_submit/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snakemake/executors/__init__.py", line 1233, in run
```

I should mention, that two of the variables are empty and that I expect the tabs/whitespaces in the echo command.

Does anybody have an explanation, why snakemake is trying to find output in the wildcards? I am expecially confused, because it is printing the correct command.

Comment: That's odd! What snakemake version are you using? Does the line (23) correspond with the same rule? Can you make a minimal example that we can run ourselves too?

Comment: yes, the line corresponds to the same rule. I have no Idea what went wrong, but apparently it was an unrelated error (it suddenly worked again, probably some server problems).

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this same problem.
The issue is probably in how you invoked Snakemake from the command line.
For example, this was my Snakefile rule:

```py
rule sort:
    input:
        "{file}.bam",
    output:
        "{file}.sorted.bam",
        "{file}.sorted.bai",
    shell:
        "sambamba sort {input}"
```

I don't even have `params` or `wildcards` explicitly anywhere in there.
But when I run it on my Slurm HPC I get the same error:

```sh
snakemake -j 10 -c "sbatch {cluster.params}" -u cluster.yaml
```

The `Wildcards` (note the capital "W") and `params` objects weren't from the rule.
They came from the cluster execution of the rule, and the error was thrown when trying to parse the `cluster.yaml` file.

There was no cluster parameter specification in my `cluster.yaml` file for the `sort` rule, so the error was thrown.
I fixed this by adding

```yaml
sort:
    params: "..."
```

to my `cluster.yaml` file.
In your case, add cluster submission options under a `create_tasks: ...` list.
You can also add a `__default__: ...` list as the default submission parameters for any job, by default, unless it matches another rule.